# Android java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection on Html POST

Tags: android, json, post, response, ioexception

I have a problem with my app.
I manage to get a html "GET" with response with no problem, but when i try to "POST" it get java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection
The GET and the POST code is in the same activity, the GET is in the onCreate() and the POST is with button click.

It seems every time it tries to get information about responecode, responsemessage, getInputStream etc...

My code:

```
private class PostClass2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private final Context context;
    public PostClass2(Context c){
        this.context = c;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://speedport.ip/data/InternetConnectionS1P1.json");
        HttpURLConnection connection2 = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        String urlParameters = "t_password="+t_passwordout+"&other_name="+providerout+"&other_user="+usernameout+"&other_password="+passout+"&showpw="+showpwin+"&always_online=1&idle_time=2";
        connection2.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection2.setRequestProperty("Expert Info (Chat/Sequence)", "/data/InternetConnectionS1P1.json");
        connection2.setRequestProperty("Request URI", "/data/InternetConnectionS1P1.json");
        connection2.setRequestProperty("Request Version", "HTTP/1.1");
        connection2.setRequestProperty("Host", "speedport.ip");
        connection2.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        connection2.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*");
        connection2.setRequestProperty("Origin","http://speedport.ip");
        connection2.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        connection2.setRequestProperty("USER-AGENT", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36");
        connection2.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection2.setRequestProperty("Referer", "http://speedport.ip/html/assistent/internet/internetconnection_wizard_step1_part1.html");
        connection2.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        connection2.setRequestProperty("ACCEPT-LANGUAGE", "hu-HU,hu;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
        connection2.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookietoheader);
        connection2.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream dStream = new DataOutputStream(connection2.getOutputStream());
        dStream.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        dStream.flush();
        dStream.close();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Params: "+urlParameters);
        final StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("Request URL " + url);
        output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Type " + "GET");
        output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Cookie " + cookietoheader);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection2.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder responseOutput = new StringBuilder();
        System.out.println("output===============" + br);
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            responseOutput.append(line);
        }
        br.close();
        output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Response " + System.getProperty("line.separator") + System.getProperty("line.separator") + responseOutput.toString());
        outtotext2 = responseOutput.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void ignored) {
        t.setText(textout1);
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
04-10 19:49:24.395  21986-22074/com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224 W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{speedport.ip:80, proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress=192.168.1.254 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)
04-10 19:49:24.400  21986-22074/com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:210)
04-10 19:49:24.400  21986-22074/com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:80)
04-10 19:49:24.400  21986-22074/com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:904)
04-10 19:49:24.400  21986-22074/com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:788)
04-10 19:49:24.400  21986-22074/com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:443)
04-10 19:49:24.400  21986-22074/com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:388)
04-10 19:49:24.400  21986-22074/com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseMessage(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:497)
04-10 19:49:24.400  21986-22074/com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224 W/System.err﹕ at com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224.MainSetupActivity$PostClass2.doInBackground(MainSetupActivity.java:274)
04-10 19:49:24.400  21986-22074/com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224 W/System.err﹕ at com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224.MainSetupActivity$PostClass2.doInBackground(MainSetupActivity.java:233)
04-10 19:49:24.400  21986-22074/com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
04-10 19:49:24.400  21986-22074/com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224 W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-10 19:49:24.400  21986-22074/com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
04-10 19:49:24.400  21986-22074/com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224 W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
04-10 19:49:24.400  21986-22074/com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224 W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
04-10 19:49:24.400  21986-22074/com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224 W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
04-10 19:49:24.400  21986-22074/com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224 W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: size=0 content=...
04-10 19:49:24.400  21986-22074/com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:200)
04-10 19:49:24.400  21986-22074/com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:191)
04-10 19:49:24.400  21986-22074/com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224 W/System.err﹕ ... 14 more
```

Wireshark:

```
POST /data/InternetConnectionS1P1.json HTTP/1.1\r\n
    [Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): POST /data/InternetConnectionS1P1.json HTTP/1.1\r\n]
    Request Method: POST
    Request URI: /data/InternetConnectionS1P1.json
    Request Version: HTTP/1.1
Host: speedport.ip\r\n
Connection: keep-alive\r\n
Content-Length: 168\r\n
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*\r\n
Origin: http://speedport.ip\r\n
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest\r\n
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36\r\n
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n
Referer: http://speedport.ip/html/assistent/internet/internetconnection_wizard_step1_part1.html\r\n
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n
Accept-Language: hu-HU,hu;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4\r\n
Cookie: session_id=09F261CE13FBAAC7\r\n
```

Comment: Do any printing in onPostExecute()

Comment: In my code at the moment i dont do any
show i do?

Comment: what data you send as "POST" data?

Comment: I want to send the url paramethers. I want to change passwords and etc

Comment: I added this code but still dont work with the same error:

Comment: DataOutputStream dStream = new DataOutputStream(connection2.getOutputStream());
            dStream.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            dStream.flush();
            dStream.close();

Comment: You are using an async task right?

Comment: private class PostClass2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
yeah i do

Comment: KISHORE_ZE  i added my wireshark that is used to create the header, i think may that can be the problem?

Comment: What If u switched params to string and string void. And return string. Check this out for more info http://www.androidauthority.com/use-remote-web-api-within-android-app-617869/

Comment: @KISHORE_ZE i will give a try i will let you know if it succed, thank you :)

Comment: @KISHORE_ZE how i can do that what you said? I beginner in programing :(

Comment: @KISHORE_ZE I Edited my question, i put the whole class now

Comment: Where did u get this code from? Did u make it or did u get it from a website. If website tell me which one and also a link to the api website thanks!

Comment: I managed to get it work, the problem was, that there need to be a plusz parameter in parameters what i didn't saw till now(it is from the webpage's source code thats why)
@KISHORE_ZE thank you for helping me :)

Comment: Its ok. Remember to post your answer for this question as reference to future readers. :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it work, the problem was, that there need to be a plus parameter in parameters what i didn't saw till now(it is from the webpage's source code thats why)